# OP Amp in need of some resistors

Tags: operational-amplifier, kirchhoffs-laws

This scheme represents an DAC and an op amp.I need to find R1 and R2 so I came up with this resolve.

```
 (Vout has to be between [-10,10) V and Vr=10V,Rr=5k)  

 I1=current through R1,I2 current through R2.




 Vout = R2*I2;(Kirchoff Vout,through R2 to the negative ground)
 I1+I2-I=0 ==>I2=I+I1;(Kirchoff in node A)
 I=Vr/Rr ==>I= 10V/5k==>I=2 mA;
 I-I1=0=>I=I1=>I1=2mA;(not sure about this,node B)
 10V(the superior limit)=R2*I2=>R2=10V/4mA=>R2=2.5k ,so R2 has to   be                
 below 2.5 kohms 

 thus R1=Vr/I1 =>R1=5 kohms
[![enter image description here][1]][1] Do you think I have mistaken in my thinking here?
```

[image]

Comment: I was asking if I did correctly the Kirchhoff in node B.I do not know for sure if I am correct.

Comment: Do you have a data sheet link to the DAC? Have you read the data sheet?

Comment: Yes,the only useful thing I have is that it puts out 2 mA

Comment: "Yes" you have a data sheet link or "yes" you have read the data sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data sheet I believe is [here](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data.../DAC08.pdf) and the relevant picture in the data sheet is here: -

[image]

Always read the data sheet first and then reflect on the values they propose to see if they are suitable.

Comment: Thank you ,it offered more help than others.I will look at the datasheet more carefully next time.